# C# error net.minecraft.client.main.Main

Tags: c#, java, minecraft, launcher

Im trying to create own launcher for my server, but i could not run the game.

```
string launch=  "-XX:HeapDumpPath=MojangTricksIntelDriversForPerformance_javaw.exe_minecraft.exe.heapdump -Xms512m -Xmx1024m -jar "+
        "-Djava.library.path=" + "\"" +
        @"C:\Users\Skicek\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\versions\1.6.4\1.6.4-natives-AL74" +"\""+ " -cp " + "\"" +
        @"C:\Users\Skicek\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\net\sf\jopt-simple\jopt-simple\4.5\jopt-simple-4.5.jar"  + "\";" + "\"" +
        @"C:\Users\Skicek\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\paulscode\codecjorbis\20101023\codecjorbis-20101023.jar"  + "\";" + "\"" +
        @"C:\Users\Skicek\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\paulscode\codecwav\20101023\codecwav-20101023.jar"  + "\";" + "\"" +
        @"C:\Users\Skicek\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\paulscode\libraryjavasound\20101123\libraryjavasound-20101123.jar" + "\";" + "\"" +
        @"C:\Users\Skicek\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\paulscode\librarylwjglopenal\20100824\librarylwjglopenal-20100824.jar" + "\";" + "\"" +
        @"C:\Users\Skicek\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\paulscode\soundsystem\20120107\soundsystem-20120107.jar" + "\";" + "\"" +
        @"C:\Users\Skicek\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\argo\argo\2.25_fixed\argo-2.25_fixed.jar" + "\";" + "\"" +
        @"C:\Users\Skicek\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\bouncycastle\bcprov-jdk15on\1.47\bcprov-jdk15on-1.47.jar" + "\";" + "\"" +
        @"C:\Users\Skicek\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\google\guava\guava\14.0\guava-14.0.jar" + "\";" + "\"" +
        @"C:\Users\Skicek\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\apache\commons\commons-lang3\3.1\commons-lang3-3.1.jar" + "\";" + "\"" +
        @"C:\Users\Skicek\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\commons-io\commons-io\2.4\commons-io-2.4.jar" + "\";" + "\"" +
        @"C:\Users\Skicek\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\net\java\jinput\jinput\2.0.5\jinput-2.0.5.jar" + "\";" + "\"" +
        @"C:\Users\Skicek\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\net\java\jutils\jutils\1.0.0\jutils-1.0.0.jar" + "\";" + "\"" +
        @"C:\Users\Skicek\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\com\google\code\gson\gson\2.2.2\gson-2.2.2.jar" + "\";" + "\"" +
        @"C:\Users\Skicek\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\lwjgl\lwjgl\lwjgl\2.9.0\lwjgl-2.9.0.jar" + "\";" + "\"" +
        @"C:\Users\Skicek\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\lwjgl\lwjgl\lwjgl_util\2.9.0\lwjgl_util-2.9.0.jar" + "\";" + "\"" +
        @"C:\Users\Skicek\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\lwjgl\lwjgl\lwjgl-platform\2.9.0\lwjgl-platform-2.9.0-natives-windows.jar" + "\";" + "\"" +
        @"C:\Users\Skicek\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\net\java\jinput\jinput-platform\2.0.5\jinput-platform-2.0.5-natives-windows.jar" + "\";" + "\"" +
        @"C:\Users\Skicek\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\versions\1.6.4\1.6.4.jar" + "\"" + 
         " net.minecraft.client.main.Main --username Player --session OFFLINE_MODE --version 1.6.4 "+
         "--gameDir " +"\""+ @"C:\Users\Skicek\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft"  + "\" " +
         "--assetsDir " +"\""+ @"C:\Users\Skicek\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\assets\virtual\legacy" + "\"" ;


        Process test = new Process();
        test.StartInfo.FileName = "java.exe";
        test.StartInfo.Arguments = launch;
        test.Start();
```

All the time im getting "unable to access jarfile net.minecraft.client.main.Main

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not specifying the jar file to run in your arguments:

```
"-jar " + "-Djava.library.path="
```

The first argument after `-jar` must be the path to the jar you are running.